# To get path name with url values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an example URL.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?a=1&b=2
```

**question**: I need to fetch path name along with url values like this

```
/questions/ask?a=1&b=2
```

I need jquery or javascript solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?a=1&b=2';
alert(url.pathname + url.search);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/8XYYj/